# Sharing docker clusters

Tags: docker

I thought a major benefit of Docker was the ability to deploy a single unit of work (a container) that is cheap, lightweight, and boots fast, instead of having to deploy a more expensive and heavy VM that boots slowly. But everywhere I look (eg AWS, Docker Cloud, IBM, Azure, Google Cloud, kubernetes), deploying single containers is not an option. Instead, a single customer must deploy entire VMs that will run instances of the docker engine which will then host clusters of containers.

Is there any CaaS that allows you to deploy only as few containers as you need? I thought many cloud provider companies would offer this service, coordinating the logistics of which containers submitted by which customers to group together and distribute among the companies' docker engines. I see this service is unnecessary for those customers that will be deploying enough containers that a full docker engine instance is necessary. But what about those customers that want the cheap option of only deploying a single container?

If this service is not available, I see Docker containers as no cheaper nor lighter in weight than full VMs. In both cases, you pay for a heavy VM. The only remaining benefit would be isolation of processes and the ability to quickly change them.

Again, is there any cloud service available to deploy only a single container?

Comment: Hey, void you clarify what the question is here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see here, the problem is the point of view of your approach, not Docker.

Any machine that runs a GNU-Linux distro can run the docker daemon and therefore, run your docker containers.

There are solutions like [Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker-singlecontainer-deploy.html) that allow you to deploy docker containers with a high level of abstraction, making your "ops" part a little bit easier.

Nevertheless, I wonder, how do you actually try to deploy your application? what do you mean with:

> "Instead, a single customer must deploy entire VMs that will run
>   instances of the docker engine which will then host clusters of
>   containers."

?

For example, kubernetes is a framework that allows you to deploy containers in other machines, so yes, you have to have a Framework for that or, instead, use a Framework as a service as Elastic Beankstalk is.

I hope my answer helps!

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about Elastic Beanstalk. Its what you didn't say that answered my question. I'm not missing some important piece of info, but as you say, I am just approaching docker from the wrong perspective.